# Disable open Google Search by sliding up from the home button "feature"?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, settings, samsung-galaxy-nexus, google-search

Galaxy Nexus running Android version 4.1.1.

After a recent update, it seems google has added a feature where you can place your finger on the bottom home buttons, and slide up, to open google search. This feature is extremely useful when I want to interrupt my game play to open a google search while running the streets of liberty city. I am wondering if anyone knows how to disable this wonderful feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler solution that doesn't require root access is to go into Settings then Apps. From there, disable Google Search. This will also disable the homescreen searchbar and Google Now features.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I wish I could make use of the extra screen space though. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: [you can](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2687515/ "How to customize the Google Now swipe-up gesture") if chosing a different path :)

Comment: My phone (Android 5.0) no longer has Google Search. Any idea about what to disable now to block this feature?

Answer (score 2):

> But again, these solutions require you to be rooted. I don't know how
>   only to disable the swipe feature...

...I do!! How about creating a launcher that does nothing, but instead of the home button, use the swipe gesture? [Google Now Swipe Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianCampos.googlenowswipedisabler) does just that! I know I'm a little late, but if you're still wondering, or if someone else comes across this thread, I hope it will help. But the main point of this is to keep ALL of Google Search's features, except the swipe without rooting, or doing any other messy work.

Comment: That app is gone for good. For those wanting this way, take a look at alternatives as [SwipeLaunch Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hk.sld.SwipeLaunchDisabler) – or the new app from the original app's dev, [Swipeup Utility](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianCampos.swipeuputility).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not you want to remove Google Now in its entirety or just disable the swipe gesture. If you are ok with disabling Google Now, and you are rooted, you can remove the Velvet.apk file (or add .bak after the name) from /system/app. You could also disable it from Applications under settings.

But again, these solutions require you to be rooted. I don't know how only to disable the swipe feature...

Answer (score 0):

The links in the previous answers seems dead.
I just developed an app to disable this annoying feature, enjoy ;-)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulk.gesturedisabler

Comment: Is this only for the Nexus, as its name suggests – or should it work on other devices as well?

Answer (score -2):

To unlock the screen you can swipe from anywhere and to any direction. Ignore the arrow.

Google search will only appears if you swiped up from the bottom of the screen. That's what the arrow is meant for.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to disable the Google Search swipe.